# g1 and g1gc should be synonyms

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

StackOverflow has tags for [g1](/questions/tagged/g1) and [g1gc](/questions/tagged/g1gc).  [g1](/questions/tagged/g1) has more questions, but to my mind [g1gc](/questions/tagged/g1gc) is more descriptive.  Can [g1](/questions/tagged/g1) be removed and made a synonym of [g1gc](/questions/tagged/g1gc)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure that the [G1 Garbage Collector](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html) even needs its own tag, but I don't have a problem with it either.

On the other hand, I'm pretty sure that the [HTC Dream (alias G1)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream) *doesn't* need its own tag (it *was* the first Android handset, but doesn't really have any real-world impact these days). [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144254/getting-started-with-android) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495734/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-an-android-app-from-being-removed) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352950/android-program-crashing-new-to-platform) [five questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g1) [g1](/questions/tagged/g1) are actually about this phone (however, all 3 of them are actually generic Android questions and not really G1-specific).

*If* the G1 GC gets its own tag, I'd vote for [g1gc](/questions/tagged/g1gc) (or better yet: [g1-gc](/questions/tagged/g1-gc)) just to avoid any potential confusion and tag misuse.

<strike>**And** [g1](/questions/tagged/g1) is *gone*. I've just retagged that last such question as [g1gc](/questions/tagged/g1gc).</strike> (actually, I was looking at the wrong tab). I can't retag those as [g1-gc](/questions/tagged/g1-gc), as it only differs in punctuation.

Comment: Is this answered then?  The g1 tag is still present, and you make good points about it not really being necessary these days.